# Message- Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django

Tags: package-management, python, django

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I love it so far. I have been trying to install Django for a website development project.
In the terminal, when I start the python interpreter and type

```
import django 
django.VERSION
```

I face no issues and get

```
(1, 8, 2, 'final', 0)
```

Then, to start my project, I typed

```
django-admin startproject trialsite
```

and I got a message saying

```
Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django
```

I installed django using `pip install Django==1.8.2` and also installed the django-admin package before using it via apt-get. Also, I have been following the Django book as a guide through the whole process. Can someone tell me what the issue is?

---

**EDIT:**
My `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and `site-packages` are both empty. I don't know if this is important. But according to the django book, this is where `django-admin` should be.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a number of different ways in which you can install Django depending upon your needs and how you want to configure your development environment.

- Global Install from Packages:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install python-django
  ```

  You can test that the installation was successful by typing:

  ```
  django-admin --version
  ```
- Global Install through pip:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

  Now you can install pip. If you plan on using Python version 2, install using the following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python-pip
  ```

  If, instead, you plan on using Python 3, use this command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python3-pip
  ```

  Now that you have pip, we can easily install Django. If you are using Python 2, you can type:

  ```
  sudo pip install django
  ```

  If you are using Python 3, use the pip3 command instead:

  ```
  sudo pip3 install django
  ```

  You can verify that the installation was successful by typing:

  ```
  django-admin --version
  ```
- Global Install through pip.
- Global Install through pip.

full Details and all rights goes to the owner from [digitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: thank you. I am confused though. I used sudo apt-get install python-django, and it worked.
But when I used pip install Django==1.8.2, even that installed django right?

Comment: It is the same. 1.8.2

Comment: I suppose specifying version was the problem